# Remove substring from both ends of an std::string?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I'm trying to remove some start and end delimiters in a std::string. Is there a built in or better way to do this?

Here is my current way:

```cpp
std::string sub = "~test.txt~";
std::string str = "~test.txt~The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.~test.txt~";

str = str.substr(sub.length(), str.length() - sub.length() * 2);
```

Start and end delimiters are exactly the same, and they are located at the very edges.

Expected value is `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`.

Comment: Do you have to check prefix/suffix before removing them?

Comment: @Jarod42 The start and end delimiters are the same, and theyre always located at the very ends. Updated my question for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct (for this constrained case) and efficient (assuming that you need a `std::string` result; `std::string_view` might be good if you’re using C++17).  If it’s ugly, make it a function so that the rest of the code can use

```
std::string mid=remove2(whole, delim);
```

…although that’s *not* efficient in the case of

```
remove2(whole, "literal")
```

which allocates memory just to count the characters whose number is already known at compile time.  If that matters, you could add an overload that took a length and write

```
remove2(whole, sizeof("literal")-1)
```

Comment: A needless extra-allocation is certainly not *efficient*.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the function, though its only done in one place in the code. I'll keep my current code in my question then since I'm using C++11 for now.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Why do you call it *extra*?  We don’t know enough to say whether the `string` created is used for something that would not support a pointer/length pair.  (For example, the source could be already a `const std::string` and the result could be used with a `const char*`.)

Comment: Considering that there is a solution without any allocation, the one allocation is "extra".

Comment: @Deduplicator: Show how to get the result as a NTBS without allocating or writing to the original and we’re set.

Comment: @Davis: Now you are moving the goal-posts.

Comment: @Deduplicator: As I said, we don’t have enough information to exclude that as the use case.  So it **might** be inefficient; I already conditioned “efficient” on needing the result as a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with your code is that [`.substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) creates a new `std::string`, resulting in an expensive allocation (unless the result is small enough for SSO to work).

Use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) to fix that:

```
str = std::string_view(str).substr(sub.length(), str.length() - sub.length() * 2);
```

Alternatively, use [`.assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign):

```
str.assign(str.begin() + sub.length(), str.end() - sub.length());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, though I'm only working with C++11 right now. but definitely I'll try the `.assign()` also.